# Tkinter: return self.func(*args)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python and can't get a test program functioning. The goal was to create an address book using objects to hold information. The widget runs but when a button is clicked instead of updating I get the error

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\neuvillerl\Desktop\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\neuvillerl\workspace\vtk_testing\wid.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    btns = Tkinter.Button(nam, text = x.get_name(), command= lambda x=x: update(x),bg = 'blue', fg = 'white')

  File "C:\Users\neuvillerl\workspace\vtk_testing\wid.py", line 61, in update
    lbl5.configure(nam, text = "name: " + str(person.get_name()))

  File "C:\Users\neuvillerl\Desktop\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1331, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\Users\neuvillerl\Desktop\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1322, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: unknown option "-colormap""
```

And the code :

```
nam = Tkinter.Tk()

class person(object):


def __init__(self, name, phone, address, email):
    self.name = name
    self.phone = phone
    self.address = address
    self.email = email

def get_name(self):
    return self.name
def get_phone(self):
    return self.phone
def get_address(self):
    return self.address
def get_email(self):
    return self.email

riley = person("Riley", "XXX-XXX-XXXX", "This place", "email1@hi.com")
alex = person("Alex","XXX-XXX-XXXX", "That place", "email2@hi.com")
maggie = person("Maggie","XXX-XXX-XXXX","Other place","email3@hi.com")
lst = [riley,alex,maggie]
def update(person):
    lbl5.configure(nam, text = "name: " + str(person.get_name()))
    lbl6.configure(nam, text = "phone#: " + str(person.get_phone()))
    lbl7.configure(nam, text = "address: " + str(person.get_address()))
    lbl8.configure(nam, text = "email: " + str(person.get_email()))
lbl5 = Tkinter.Label(nam, text = "name:" )
lbl6 = Tkinter.Label(nam, text = "phone#:" )
lbl7 = Tkinter.Label(nam, text = "address:" )
lbl8 = Tkinter.Label(nam, text = "email:" )

for x in lst:
    btns = Tkinter.Button(nam, text = x.get_name(), command= lambda x=x: 
 update(x),bg = 'blue', fg = 'white')
    btns.pack(fill = Tkinter.X)
lbl5.pack()
lbl6.pack()
lbl7.pack()
lbl8.pack()
nam.mainloop()`
```

Comment: that's not the error message, it's telling you the name of the function. please include the whole error message

Comment: updated. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are passing the `nam` instance as first argument to the `Label.configure` method. Your fuction should be:

```
def update(person):
    lbl5.configure(text = "name: " + str(person.get_name()))
    lbl6.configure(text = "phone#: " + str(person.get_phone()))
    lbl7.configure(text = "address: " + str(person.get_address()))
    lbl8.configure(text = "email: " + str(person.get_email()))
```